# Bootstrap Grid isn't working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I installed Bootstrap for my Rails and decided to test out making a grid. This is my code.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span4">
    <h1>About the Creator</h1>
        <p>

        </p>
  </div>

      <div class="span8">
        <h1>About the Site</h1>
            <p>

            </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDubN.png) is what it looks like. As you can see, it's in 2 rows, however it should be in 2 columns. There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code itself as far as I can see. I don't think I made a mistake during installation, because when I installed bootstrap, it automatically stylized my webapp. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of bootstrap are you using? In recent versions of bootstrap the syntax is `<tag class="col-xs-4">` rather than `<tag class="span4">`

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <h1>About the Creator</h1>
        <p>

        </p>
  </div>

      <div class="col-xs-8">
        <h1>About the Site</h1>
            <p>

            </p>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This fixed it. I am using the most recent version, however the tutorial hasn't been updated I guess.

Comment: No problem! If you're looking for a more updated tutorial I would look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/, I think it lays the concepts out clearly.

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 classes you can use in order to specify column size:

```
col-xs-#
col-sm-#
col-md-#
col-lg-#
```

They were introduced so that you could have columns have different portions of the screen on different platforms. For example, perhaps you want your main content to take up 12 columns, instead of 10, on a mobile phone. TO do this do:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```